# change alpha of a child view without changing alpha of parent view

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have two uiviews 1 child and 1 parent parent view has alpha .30 on click of button I want to change alpha of child view to 1.0 or 0.0 is this possible if yes then how.

Please enlighten me on this.

Thanx in advance
:)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with
the alpha property of `UIView` and This value affects only the current view and does not affect any of its embedded subviews.

Read the Apple Documentation for `alpha` in `UIView`.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

Updated:Try with below

```
[parentView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5]];
[childView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor clearColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];
```

Comment: unless I am mistaken the alpha property is taken into account by the child views too. The one which is not is the alpha of the backgroundcolor of the view.

Comment: @Ankit Sachan: Did you try to use the alpha property of UIView .

Comment: That is not correct. I just tested it on my device and all the subviews become transparent too when setting alpha to 0.5 on a parent view, no matter what the apple docs state.

Comment: The problem is that with the backgroundColor the contents of the view itself do not become more or less transparent (e.g. the text in a UILabel, or the contents of a UIImageView)

Comment: @Joris Mans : Yes Agree with you but we could also apply the same on UILabel, UIImageView ..

Answer (score 1):

you want to make the child view less transparent than the parent view? That is not possible using the alpha property.

Comment: i want to make child view more visible than parent view