# Subview has higher alpha then parent?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, parent-child, alpha

I am programming in Xcode 6.1.1 with objective-c.

I have two UIViewcontrollers (one parent and one child).
The parent has an alpha of 0.7.
What I would like to have is an child with an higher alpha then it's parent. I would like to have the child an alpha of 1.0.

I searched on this topic and found this one:[change alpha of a child view without changing alpha of parent view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701604/change-alpha-of-a-child-view-without-changing-alpha-of-parent-view)

It's an old one and is not working at all.

Question: How to make the alpha of an child higher then the parent viewcontroller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't make the alpha of a child view appear higher (less transparent) than its parent view.

A child view's effective alpha is determined by its own alpha times the alpha of its parent view.

What you can do it put both views into a common container view. Make the container view have a clear background color. Then the two views can each have their own alpha.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try that out. I get the point that the child inherit the properties from the parent, but it would make things much less complicated when this would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The effective alpha of any view is the alpha value of itself multiplied by the alpha value of its parents.

So if you have a view with an alpha of 0.6 and a subview with an alpha of 1.0 then the subview will appear to have an alpha of 0.6 also.

If the subview has an alpha of 0.5 then it will appear to have an alpha of 0.3.